# How would I make a value permanant after restarting

Tags: java, variables

Basically when someone joins my game it adds +1 to a variable, but after the game restarts the variable sets back to 0. How can I make the variable not set back to 0.

Comment: application  is restarting and you want to get the previous value,if that is what you want you should *write the value into a file and read it when your application/game starts*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write down in file system, when you shut down the game. Read the value from the file when you restart your game again.

Answer (score 2):

All logic lies on the words *"game restarts"*

**case 1 :** When game restarts,If your program not restarting(*Normally yes*).

Make that variable as a `static` variable.The value exists until your process killed.

**case 2 :** When game restarts starts your program again (*Normally no*).

Then save the value in file or database and read it again.

Comment: it depends on what they mean by "restarts" if the program doesn't terminate then this would be correct, otherwise it gets a little more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

The class `java.util.prefs.Preferences` allows you to store data persistently between invocations of the same program.